# Use Context to load JavaScript on certain pages

Tags: 7

Is it possible to load a JavaScript file on certain pages with the [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Context Add Assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets) module does *exactly* that :)

*Taken from the [README](http://drupalcode.org/project/context_addassets.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.TXT)*

> Supports adding active theme files to page via context

I've used 7.x-1.0-beta1 with no major problems, so don't be afraid that there's no full release :)